# Django rest framework reverse relation field data omitted from validated_data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

models:

```
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    ...

class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey('Questionnaire', related_name='questions', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

serializers:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = MultipleChoiceSerializer(many=True)
    children = RecursiveField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = [
            'id',
            'text',
            'order',
            'choices',
            #'parent',
            'children',
            'type',
            'category',
            'requiredif',
            'max_answers',
            'min_answers',
        ]

class QuestionnaireCreateUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questions = QuestionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Questionnaire
        fields = [
            'id',
            'questions',
            'name',
            'description',
        ]

        def create(self, validated_data):
            print validated_data
            ...
```

validated_data using `{'name': 'a', 'description': 'b', 'questions': [{'category': 'a', 'min_answers': 1}]}`:

```
{u'name': u'a', u'questions': [], u'description': u'b'}
```

simple test:

```
def test_submit_qnr(self):
        self.client.force_login(self.user.user)
        qnr2 = {'name': 'a', 'description': 'b', 'questions': [{'category': 'a', 'min_answers': 1}]}
        response = self.client.post('/api/qnr/', data=qnr2)
        print response.json()
        response.json()['questions'].should_not.equal([])  # fails!
```

JSON response:

```
{u'description': u'b', u'id': 1, u'questions': [], u'name': u'a'}
```

I would like to write nested fields and have overridden `create` to do so, but there seems to be an issue with validation, in that the data for the nested models is deleted in the validated_data.
I tried printing the `validated_data` variable at the top of the create function and for reasons I don't understand the `questions` field is an empty list. The relations section in the api-guide documentation shows almost this exact same example. What am I missing?

EDIT1:

The serializer works as expected when tested directly in the shell, but for some reason it fails in the test case

EDIT 2:
View:

```
class QuestionnaireViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication, JSONWebTokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
    queryset = Questionnaire.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionnaireCreateUpdateSerializer
```

URLs:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'qnr', QuestionnaireViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    ]
```

Comment: Can you also add the `QuestionSerializer`?

Comment: @AKS added the serializer

Comment: Everything looks alright here. Did you try to do this in console as shown in the api-guide [example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)?

Comment: @AKS when testing the serializer directly in the shell, it works as expected. But not in the test case.

Comment: Can you try adding `format='json'` in your `client.post` call?

Comment: @AKS I am now getting a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'OrderedDict'` but at least the `questions` list isn't empty... a step in the right direction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105332/discussion-between-aks-and-verbal-kint).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you followed the example provided in the api-guide and it works in shell I think that the data is not being sent properly.

Django Rest Framework uses [`APIClient`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient) for testing which is based on Django's [`Test Client`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client)

If you don't provide a `content type` the default value is `multipart/form-data`

> If you don’t provide a value for `content_type`, the values in `data` will be transmitted with a content type of `multipart/form-data`. In this case, the key-value pairs in data will be encoded as a `multipart` message and used to create the `POST` data payload.

You will need to explicitly specify the `format` of the data as `json`:

```
response = self.client.post('/api/qnr/', data=qnr2, format='json')
```